# Angular - How to bind a button for different uses?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, frontend

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript.

I have to do a button that can have a Text or an Icon or Text + Icon.

Example:

**button-icon-text-component.html**

```html
<button>
  TEST BUTTON
</button>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-button-icon-text {here I have to choose beetwen TEXT or ICON}></app-button-icon-text>
```

**button-icon-text-component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-icon-text',
  templateUrl: './button-icon-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-icon-text.component.css']
})
export class ButtonIconTextComponent implements OnInit {

{ADD SOME LOGIC}

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Input` decorator and set `'TEXT'` or `'ICON'` on it.

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmnp2u

**app.component.html:**

```html
<app-button-icon-text type="TEXT"></app-button-icon-text>
```

**button-icon-text-component.ts:**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-icon-text',
  templateUrl: './button-icon-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-icon-text.component.css']
})
export class ButtonIconTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  type // TEXT or ICON

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**button-icon-text-component.html:**

```html
<button *ngIf="type === 'TEXT'">
  TEST BUTTON
</button>
...
```

Comment: Hi @zmag, thanks.
My problem is this, I don't know how to differentiate the Text type from the Icon type.
So I don't know what to insert in input or ngOnInit.
Could you be more complete?

Comment: Try *ngIf syntax. I've made stackblitz sample and updated my post. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmnp2u

Comment: Ok, thanks! I customized it for my project using your idea!
Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 2):

These are mine 3 examples:

For the icons I installed: npm i material-icons

Then I imported material in style.css: @import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';

app.component.html

```
//text button
<app-button-icon-text [text]="'test'"></app-button-icon-text>
  <br><br>

//iconbutton
  <app-button-icon-text [icon]="'face'"></app-button-icon-text>
  <br><br>

//icon + text button
  <app-button-icon-text [text]="'test'" [icon]="'face'"></app-button-icon-text>
```

button-icon-text.component.html

```
<button>
  <span *ngIf="icon"  class="material-icons">{{icon}}</span>
  {{text}}
</button>
```

button-icon-text.component.html

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-icon-text',
  templateUrl: './button-icon-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-icon-text.component.css']
})
export class ButtonIconTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  text;

  @Input()
  icon;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```